# JSONBuilder using OutputStreamWriter

Tags: json, grails, groovy, jax-rs

I am trying to create JSON using grails.web.JSONBuilder. Is there a way to use the OutputStreamWriter in the JSONBuilder(like the MarkUpBuilder has)? If not, what is the easiest way to create JSON using JSONBuilder? A simple example would be helpful. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A grails guide has a starting point for this: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.1.7%20XML%20and%20JSON%20Responses  as far as code sample here ya go:

```
def listCounts = {
        render ([data:[
            //Unassigned
            unassigned:Task.activeOnly.open.unassigned.count(),
            //Open
            open:Task.activeOnly.open.count(),
            //My
            my:Task.activeOnly.open.my("username").count(),
            //Review
            review:Task.activeOnly.myReview("username").count()
        ]] as JSON)
    }
```

essentially any map rendered as JSON will spit out JSON

Comment: I am using the custom DomainObjectWriter(using JAXRS). So I can't use the render method. I want to use grails.web.JSONBuilder. For example, I have something like this for xml content-type :                                                                        def writer = new OutputStreamWriter(entityStream, charset)
 def builder = new MarkupBuilder(writer)